# tex4ebook texlive installation failure on cygwin on windows

Tags: installing, windows, make4ht, tex4ebook, cygwin

I am trying to give `tex4ebook` or `make4ht` a try, but I get the following messages on my console.

```
$ tex4ebook lsdas15f
/usr/bin/tex4ebook:6: module 'lapp-mk4' not found:
        no field package.preload['lapp-mk4']
        [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'lapp-mk4'
        [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'lapp-mk4'
```

or else

```
$ make4ht
/usr/bin/make4ht:7: module 'make4ht-logging' not found:
        no field package.preload['make4ht-logging']
        [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-logging'
        [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-logging'
```

My guess is that I am missing some Lua packages in the process, but I am clueless as to how to track the dependencies on this complicated setup: I am running TeXLive on Cygwin64 on a Win10 box.

Comment: Do you have full TeX Live 2021 installed? `make4ht-logging` could be missing in some earlier versions, but `lapp-mk4` is core file that `tex4ebook` and `make4ht` required since beginning, so it is really strange that it is missing.

Comment: don't know; but I usually install only what I need. I hate bloatware.

Comment: I checked sources of both `tex4ebook` and `make4ht`, and the missing files are the first libraries they require. So it seems that you have installed only `tex4ebook` and `make4ht` scripts, but not Lua modules they require. I think that `tlmgr install make4ht`, `tlmgr install tex4ht` and `tlmgr install tex4ebook` should install all necessary files, unless something is broken.

Comment: I did a search for the files and found them in their proper places, but the kpse library could not find them. I therefore updated the libraries as usual (per `mktexlsr`) and kpse could find them. there must be something broken in the installation scripts for cygwin. Didn't have to use `tlmgr`, so I can't tell about that.